# Codechef KCHAR wrong answer

Tags: algorithm

Recently I was solving the following [problem on codechef](https://www.codechef.com/LOCJUN17/problems/KCHAR):

> Alice has quarreled with Chef recently. So Chef gives a problem to Alice.
>   Initially you are given an empty string and are allowed following two operations.
>
> **Operation-1:** Every 'a' becomes 'c' and every 'c' becomes 'a'. For example, "acc" becomes "caa".
>   **Operation-2:** String is reversed. For Example, "acc" becomes "cca".
>
> Chef gives following generating equation S<sub>N</sub> = S<sub>N-1</sub> + "a" + Operation-1(Operation-2(S<sub>N-1</sub>))
>
> where S0 = "" (empty string).
>
> Alice easily finds out next few sequences as:
>
> S1 = "a"
>   S2 = "aac"
>   S3 = "aacaacc"
>
> Now Chef asks to find Kth character of S<sub>LOC</sub>, where LOC = 10<sup>2017</sup>. You need to help Alice find the answer.
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 100
>   1 ≤ K ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>

I have tried to solve the problem using following code:

```
scanf("%lld",&t);
while(t--)
{
    scanf("%lld",&k);
    count=0;
    while(1)
    {
        lg=(double)log(k)/log(2);
        av=pow(2,lg);
        if(av!=k)
        {
            diff=k-av;
            k=av-diff;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(count%2==0)
            {
                printf("a\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("c\n");
            }
            break;
        }
    }       

}
```

What is wrong in the solution?

I have tried out various inputs and I get correct answer but the I am getting WA when I submit. Can anyone provide some test cases where the solution is failing.

Comment: Did you check numerical inaccuracy for large k? It seems unlikely for large k that it can equal `pow(2, double(log(k)/log(2)))` exactly.

Comment: For example when k is `1ULL<<29`

Comment: Yes, it is giving correct answer even for k=10^18

Comment: Also -- your code is incomplete. What are the types of diff and av?

Comment: I have only shared a section of code. All variables are long long int

Comment: what is the type of `lg`? ... why not just calculate the MSB and then do a left shift? It will still be O(1) ... its not like you are saving time using inbuilt functions, you are not !!... why do you want to lose precision when you can avoid?

Comment: Also avoid using fancy inbuilt functions without getting familiar with their limitations, otherwise you will spend unnecessary time debugging the correct logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for `k=576460752303423478`. It doesn't terminate. I haven't debugged it fully, but the root cause is numerical inaccuracy: `av` should be the largest power of 2 less than or equal to `k`, but it ends up larger than `k`. I expect there's other cases that terminate but produce the wrong result.

To find the failing case, I wrote my own version of the code and tried testing it for many values of `k`. That didn't turn up anything, so then tried near-powers-of-2. That found the example above.

Here's the code that finds the problem case (here `x()` is your code, and `y()` is my code). I added `assert`s to your code which demonstrate the problem, but you can remove them and see that the code doesn't terminate.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

char x(long long int k) {
    long long int count=0;
    while(1) {
        long long int lg=(double)log(k)/log(2);
        long long int av=pow(2,lg);
        assert((av & (av-1)) == 0); // av is a power of 2
        assert(av <= k);  // ... that's at most k
        if(av!=k) {
            long long int diff=k-av;
            k=av-diff;
            count++;
        } else {
            if(count%2==0) return 'a';
            return 'c';
        }
    }
}

char y(long long int k) {
    int count = 0;
    long long int j = 1;
    while(j < k) j *= 2;
    while (1) {
        if (j == k) {
            return count % 2 ? 'c' : 'a';
        } else if (k > j) {
            k = 2*j-k;
            count += 1;
        }
        j >>= 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int t = 60;
    while(t--) {
        for (int k = -10; k < 10; k++) {
            long long int r = (1LL<<t) + k;
            if (r <= 0) continue;
            printf("%lld\n", r);
            printf("y: %c\n", y(r));
            printf("x: %c\n", x(r));
            if (x(r) != y(r)) exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While @PaulHankin explained what's wrong with you solution

Here is my accepted solution written in C++14

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define LL long long
using namespace std;

LL k;
int T;
string f(int N, LL K){
    LL len = (1LL<<N)-1;
    LL pLen = (1LL<<(N-1)) - 1;
    if(K == len/2 + 1LL) return "a";
    if(K == len - pLen/2) return "c";
    return f(N-1, K < len/2+1LL? K : K-len/2-1LL);
}

int main() {
    cin >> T;
    while(T--){
        cin >> k;
        cout << f(60, k) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My solution is based on the following key observations:

1. `S_n = S_(n-1) + "a" + REPLACE(S_(n-1), mid_point, "c")`
2. `K <= 10^18` implies `n <= 60`, which length is long enough to cover all `K`s
3. Based on 1, for each `n`, there is two special position which you know the answer of `S_n`:

   3a. `Len(S_n)/2 + 1` (which is mid point and it must be `"a"`)

   3b. `Len(S_n) - Len(S_(n-1))/2` (which is the 3/4 quartile point and it must be `"c"`)

Then the algorithm is simple: Just see if `K` is the special position of current `S_n`, if yes we have found the answer; Otherwise the answer is equal to searching relative position `K'` in `S_(n-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than performing 60 iterations every time as per shole's answer you can try this instead:

```
N = ceil(log(k)/log(2));
```

for the first iteration.